# what is **eval() mean in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading the following sample code

```
    fkwargs = dict()
    fkwargs.update(**eval('dict(' + args.dic+ ')'))
```

I understand eval means convert the string to dictionary, but I don't understand why eval had two ** in the front?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you know what ``**`` means in general, say in front of a dictionary?

Comment: You might want to give this local article a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters